# Split values inside attribute into multiple flowfiles

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a flowfile with empty content and some attributes.

I'm interested in the attribute `ids`. It contains list of ids with `,` separator.

```
1018866556,1018878837,1018522766,1018522773,1018522788,1018522790,1018522797,
1018522959,1018522963,1018522968,1018522972,1018522981,1018511143,1018511174
```

I'm using this attribute in `InvokeHTTP` processor, but sometimes errors occur due to a large amount of data.

If an error occurs I want to split values inside this attribute. I should **get two flowfiles instead of one** with the same (or close to it) number of ids inside each flowfile.

So, after transformation I expect:

1. Flowfile #1 with `ids` `1018866556,1018878837,1018522766,1018522773,1018522788,1018522790,1018522797`
2. Flowfile #2 with `ids` `1018522959,1018522963,1018522968,1018522972,1018522981,1018511143,1018511174`

If error still occurs, then split them again, etc... Like binary search but without sorting.

How to reach it?

Comment: don't you think it's better to know the limit of items supported by api? in any case i think script is the best choice.

Comment: True, but api limit is - 2000 ids, but sometimes API can't handle even 50 ids due to a large amount of data (internal server error occurs). If I'll run with 1 id per request - i'll eat quota limits. So, I need to balance it. About script: how to split 1 flowfile into 2 diffrent flowfiles? Can you please provide example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

script for `ExecuteGroovyScript` processor:

```js
def ff=session.get()
if(!ff)return

def idList = ff.ids?.split(',')
if ( idList.size()>1 ){
    def sublistSize = (idList.size()/2).round() as int
    def ffList = idList.collate(sublistSize).collect{sublist-> 
            ffOut = ff.clone(true)
            ffOut.ids = sublist.join(',')
            ffOut
        }
    REL_SUCCESS << ffList
    ff.remove()
}else{
    REL_SUCCESS << ff
}
```